# Running iRods Rest in Tomcat 7

Tags: maven, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I'm trying to run iRods Rest in Tomcat 7. The only problem is that when I'm in the manager page, I have the list of application. All of them runs exept iRods Rest and if I try to push "start" I get:

`FAIL - Application at context path /irods-rest could not be started`

This is the steps that I had follow:

- Installation of Tomcat 7 (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get)
- Installation of maven 3
- git clone https://github.com/DICE-UNC/irods-rest.git
- cd irods-rest
- mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
- Upload of the .war file on the manager page host:8080

Tell me if you need more informations or the question is too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error, but then I looked at the logs contained in /var/log/tomcat/localhost.x-x-x.log (CentOS 7):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/irods-ext/irods-rest.properties (No such file or directory)
```

So I created the directory and properties file:

```
mkdir /etc/irods-ext
vi /etc/irods-ext/irods-rest.properties
```

And added the following contents (found template in https://github.com/DICE-UNC/irods-rest/blob/master/docs/iRODSRESTAPIDocumentation.pdf):

```
irods.host=localhost
irods.port=1247
irods.zone=tempZone
utilize.packing.streams=true
auth.type=STANDARD
default.storage.resource=
web.interface.url=
cors.allow=true
```

Now everything seems to be working after I start the irods-rest application from the Tomcat manager page.